# Not able to create Contact using Sites in Salesforce using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, force.com-sites

I have created a public Site and given permissions for the guest profile with Create and Read for both Account(Only Read) and Contact. Then I have given OWD as Public Read/Write for Account and Contact.

Created a VF page, App and LWC and added VF to sites getting below error while saving the record.

**You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.**

VF Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />    
    <div id="LightningComponentid" />    
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:publicsites", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:createContact",
          { 
          },
          "LightningComponentid",
          function(cmp) {
             
          });
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

App:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="createContact"/>
</aura:application>
```

LWC -  createContact

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}>
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='AccountId'></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='FirstName'></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='LastName'></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='Email'></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create Contact">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';


export default class CreateContact extends LightningElement {
    handleSuccess(event) {
        console.log('onsuccess event recordEditForm',event.detail.id)
    }
    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log('onsubmit event recordEditForm'+ event.detail.fields);
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="urn:metadata.tooling.soap.sforce.com" fqn="createContact">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets> 
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Interestingly I can see a record is created in the backend but it is showing that error message, how to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried checking the Field Level Security, doing DML without the record edit form (an imperative call)?

Comment: Yes , it has access to fields.